# How to draw text with image in background?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, alpha

I want to make something like this python.
[image: Example Image]

I have the image in background and write text with transparent fill, so that image shows up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way I found to do it using the `Image.composite()` function which is documented [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.composite) and [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.composite).

The approach used is described (very) tersely in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358463/355230) to the question 
[Is it possible to mask an image in Python Imaging Library (PIL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358379/is-it-possible-to-mask-an-image-in-python-imaging-library-pil) by @Mark Ransom…the following is just an illustration of applying it to accomplish what you want do.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

BACKGROUND_IMAGE_FILENAME = 'cookie_cutter_background_cropped.png'
RESULT_IMAGE_FILENAME = 'cookie_cutter_text_result.png'
THE_TEXT = 'LOADED'
FONT_NAME = 'arialbd.ttf'  # Arial Bold

# Read the background image and convert to an RGB image with Alpha.
with open(BACKGROUND_IMAGE_FILENAME, 'rb') as file:
    bgr_img = Image.open(file)
    bgr_img = bgr_img.convert('RGBA')  # Give iamge an alpha channel.
    bgr_img_width, bgr_img_height = bgr_img.size
    cx, cy = bgr_img_width//2, bgr_img_height//2  # Center of image.

# Create a transparent foreground to be result of non-text areas.
fgr_img = Image.new('RGBA', bgr_img.size, color=(0, 0, 0, 0))

font_size = bgr_img_width//len(THE_TEXT)
font = ImageFont.truetype(FONT_NAME, font_size)

txt_width, txt_height = font.getsize(THE_TEXT)  # Size of text w/font if rendered.
tx, ty = cx - txt_width//2, cy - txt_height//2  # Center of text.

mask_img = Image.new('L', bgr_img.size, color=255)
mask_img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask_img)
mask_img_draw.text((tx, ty), THE_TEXT, fill=0, font=font, align='center')

res_img = Image.composite(fgr_img, bgr_img, mask_img)
res_img.save(RESULT_IMAGE_FILENAME)
res_img.show()
```

Which, using the following `BACKGROUND_IMAGE`:

[image: background image]

produced the image shown below, which is it being viewed in Photoshop so the transparent background it has would be discernible (not to scale):

[image: result image produced]

Here's an enlargement, showing the smoothly rendered edges of the characters:

[image: magnified section of resulting image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried a different approach which works with some pixelation around the border, this helped.

Comment: Bipul Jain: Glad it helped. Yes, there are other ways of doing something like this. This approach supports smooth edges because it renders the text string onto an 8-bit (`"L"` mode) image mask. It's also very general in the sense that this mask can be composed of anything—i.e. is not limited to just text characters.