# Is it possible to fill the outside of an arc/oval in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm experimenting with laying patterns of shapes on tkinter canvas.  So far I've been successful in filling a rectangle with patterns (like laying bricks) and it shows up fine:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.config(borderwidth=0.0, highlightthickness=0.0)
bbox = (0, 0, 100, 100)
x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
width = 10
height = 5
def laying_bricks():
    for even, y in enumerate(range(y1, y2, height)):    
        x = 0
        while x < x2:
            increm = width //2 if even % 2 == 0 and x == 0 else width
            x_end = x + increm
            x_end = x_end if x_end < x2 else x2
            canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x_end, y + height, fill='firebrick3', outline='khaki')
            x = x_end
laying_bricks()
# Add the final box outline for the shape
canvas.create_rectangle(*bbox)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

For sharp angles, I can either try to draw individual polygons at the ends (not preferred), or I can apply a mask to cutoff at an angle:

```
laying_bricks()
canvas.create_rectangle(*bbox)
triangulate = (0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0)
canvas.create_polygon(triangulate, fill='black')
```

However if I wanted to fill in the same pattern within an irregular shape like an arc/oval, it became not just hard but impractical to draw the individual patterns at the ends.  I *could* painfully create my own parabola for the polygon cutoff shape:

```
def create_parabola():
    points = [0, 0]
    for x in range(0, 200):
        y = 170 - sqrt(100 * x + 20)
        points.extend([x, y])
    points.extend([200, 0, 0, 0])
    canvas.create_polygon(points, fill='royalblue')
laying_bricks()
create_parabola()
```

But then again, it seems impractical especially if the canvas was bigger, and it doesn't give me the precision of placing the curve within a bounded area.

**My question thus**: is there an obvious way to fill in the "negative space" or the "outside" area of an arc/oval using tkinter? Or, is it possible to create an inverse arc/oval with fill? Or is the functionality simply limited?

Comment: I think the only way you're going to get this to work in Tkinter is to generate the patterned shape in some other environment that actually supports clipping/masking (PIL/Pillow perhaps), and add it to your Canvas as a single image.

Comment: @jasonharper I kinda figured it wasn't available, but just wanted to see if there's something I'm missing since tkinter doesn't necessarily have the best documentations around.  I edited my question to include creating my own curved polygon but it just seem painfully unnecessarily.  I haven't tried `PIL` though, so that might be a worthwhile avenue of exploration.  Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: [how-to-draw-text-with-image-in-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297272/how-to-draw-text-with-image-in-background)

Comment: The methods a `tkinter.canvas` provides only support very basic graphics operations and primitives—so it would be fairly difficult to do what you want using it. You might be able to fake it using PIL as described in my answer (and hinted-to in a follow-up comment) to the linked question in @stovfl's comment.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.  The reason why I was looking for a pure `tkinter` answer was because I wanted to stay away from external images for this particular project.  I appreciate the fact that it's probably easier if the image was pre-drawn but I wanted to see how lightweight I can keep my script.  I can absolutely understand why `tkinter` wouldn't provide that functionality though, so I already had a different patterning method for my curve, but just wanted to see if there was an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple different ways to go about this. For an arc, all you need to do is create the rest of the arc, in a color of your choosing. For example, if the arc degree is 134 degrees, we could create an arc of 226 degrees, adding up to the full 360 degrees of a circle/oval.

```
extent = 134 # How far the arc goes
canvas.create_arc(100, 100, 200, 200, extent = extent) # Create first arc
canvas.create_arc(100, 100, 200, 200, extent = (360 - extent)) 
# Create second arc with same circle
```

For the border of an oval, you have a couple options. First you could set the canvas background to the color you want, like this:

```
canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 200, 200, width = 5000, outline = 'red') 
#The width of the border is 5000
```

Which makes the border so big that it covers the entire screen. If you want to make other objects, make them after you make the initial oval.

You could also just set the background of the canvas to the color you want by using the bg operation:

```
canvas = Canvas(master, width = 750, height = 500, bg = 'red')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately you misunderstood my question.  I don't mean to draw the border for the arc/oval, I mean to draw the inverse area of the oval/arc within the boundbox.  My MCVE in the question actually produces a similar effect, but I just wanted to see if there was an easier way.