# Python Turtle: Is it possible to use layers in fill command

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I have recently been developing a software which will be used for creating fractal images. But I realized for it to fill the shapes it will need to be done in layers otherwise it will overwrite sections. Here is my current code:

```
import turtle
def CreatePolygon (turt, Side, Size):
    if Size <= 1:
        return
    else:
        #This will create a polygon of a certain size.
        #And iterate smaller polygons inside each polygon thus creating a fractal.
        for i in range (0, Side):
            turt.forward(Size)
            turt.left(360/Side)
            CreatePolygon(turt, Side, Size/(Side-1))

Size = 250
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.speed(0)
#Calling The Function
CreatePolygon (t, 5, Size)
```

My main intention is for the polygons to be filled by different colours which I understand how to do. The issue lies in the filled polygon being overwritten once the larger polygon it is inside gets filled. I'm not sure how to fix this issue as the requirements are:

- Smaller Item Gets Filled First (Inside Bigger Item).
- Bigger Item Gets Filled In Second While Not Filling In Where The Smaller Item Filled In.

Comment: If you read the [turtle module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle), it starts with _"Turtle graphics is a popular way for introducing programming to kids."_ So, it's not really meant to be used for advances graphics. It is only to teach programming. If you want advanced things, looks for a better library.

Comment: @zvone yeah thats a good point. I will look into some better libraries to use.

Comment: Relevant [is-it-possible-to-fill-the-outside-of-an-arc-oval-in-tkinter-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114928/is-it-possible-to-fill-the-outside-of-an-arc-oval-in-tkinter-canvas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have layers in Python turtle but we can still achieve the effect you want with a little bit of duplication and rearrangement of code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'cyan']

def CreatePolygon(turt, sides, size, color=0):
    if size <= 1:
        return

    # This will create a polygon of a certain size.
    turt.fillcolor(COLORS[color])

    turt.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(sides):
        turt.forward(size)
        turt.left(360 / sides)
    turt.end_fill()

    # And iterate smaller polygons inside each polygon thus creating a fractal.
    for _ in range(sides):
        turt.forward(size)
        turt.left(360 / sides)
        CreatePolygon(turt, sides, size / (sides - 1), color + 1)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

# Calling The Function
screen.tracer(False)
CreatePolygon(turtle, 5, 250)
screen.tracer(True)

screen.exitonclick()
```

We have to draw the larger polygon first, fill it, and then recursively draw the smaller polygons.

[image]

Comment: Okay thanks, that's a very good point  I didn't think of doing that.