# Calculate rendered text size in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, text-rendering

How can I calculate the text size rendered by `text` method of an `ImageDraw` object in `PIL`?
I would like to draw multiline text with a maximum box width or height for example, being able to calculate the width from the text would help me to decide where to cut the text before writing it on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the [`ImageFont.getsize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize) method. As far as I know it will handle text with embedded newlines. See example of using it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50309414/355230) of mine to another question.