# How to fill shape with image instead of color with python pil?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create these simple patterns and import an image to fill ellipse. The way I tried is not working. How can I fill this ellipse shape with an image?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1600, 1600), (0,0,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

for y in range(80, 1600, 160):
    draw.line((y, 0, y, 1600), (255,255,0), 80)

draw.ellipse((200, 100, 1400, 1500), fill='image.jpg', outline=(0,0,0))

img.save('profile_picture.jpg')
```

Comment: In the other question the mask is loaded as a separate image, you'll have to create the mask by drawing an ellipse.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, in other question is the opposite approach, but I'll try to make it work. I let you know if I make it.

Comment: You could use the technique shown in this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50309414/355230) doing it with text to do something similar with a shape like an ellipse.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably not what you're looking for, but it'd be easier to store these images as numpy arrays and set the desired contents of your target to the respective part of the image.